# How to calculate inside a foreach loop using php

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I have this code where am able to get data from the database and insert into an array and also be able to insert it back in another table in the same database but what i want is that in the data there is a **price** and if there is data available either one or two and the price when you sum it together is greater than a specific value then do something

```
<?php

session_start();
require "../db/dbconn.php";

$sql = "SELECT cartPrice FROM cart";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$datas = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $datas[] = $row;
    }
}

foreach($datas as $data) {
    
    $price = $data['cartPrice'];

    #so how do i do it if $price is greater than maybe 1000 then do this especially when it loops more than one
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO order (price) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $price);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Does anybody know how i can do this and if you don't understand i can still explain to you

Comment: Hi, just create a variable outside the loop, and keep adding $price in it and then after the loop ends, you can check that variable. Is that what you want?

Comment: What's the purpose of the first loop?

Comment: Do you mean `if($price > 1000) { /* do something */ }`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why did you tag it with arrays, mysqli and foreach? Which one of these things are you asking about? What exactly is supposed to happen here?

Comment: @Dharman yes that's what i mean

Comment: @BilalAslam Thank ou very much i didn't even think of that, it worked

Comment: @BrightShare welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from your question is that you want to calculate the sum of prices in the $datas array and apply some condition on that sum of prices. Well, you can simply just create a variable and keep adding $price in it. Then at the end of loop, apply your condition.

```
$totalPrice = 0;

foreach($datas as $data) {

$price = $data['cartPrice'];
$totalPrice = $totalPrice + $price 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO order (price) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $price);
$stmt->execute();
}

if($totalPrice > 1000) {
   # DO SOMETHING
 }
```

Comment: i did the if statement inside the foreach loop and it worked better for me